# Read that becomes "dirty" - SQL Isolation Level

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Which of the SQL transaction isolation levels protect against a read that becomes dirty partway through a transaction?

For instance, take this schedule of two transactions, T1 and T2:

```
T1 Reads A, T2 Reads A, T1 Writes to A, T1 Commits*, T2 Writes to A, T2 Commits
```

After the starred command T1 Commits occurs, the value read by T2 is kind of "dirty." It read the committed value at the time it did its read (assuming some other long before transaction committed something to value A), but that value is no longer reflective of what is in A. Does any isolation level protect against this? Its not really a dirty read, since at the time of read, the value of A was a committed value. But if T1 and T2 are both updating the value of A,  lets say, adding 20 to its value, the result at the end of this schedule is not correct... Does only "serializable" protect against this, or does any other? I wouldn't think Repeatable Read would simply because no reads are repeated, but I am not sure...

Comment: The value read by T2 is simply no longer valid (or accurate). In this specific case, txn or not, there is just an intervening update. You are correct that `serializable` would defend against this since it effectively acquires locks on the rows it reads. More generally, you could look at other application-level approaches to optimistic locking to guard against the intervening update issue.

Comment: Thanks @barry-johnson , though I was kind of looking for a confirmation that the other isolation levels besides serializable wouldn't protect against such invalid or inaccurate reads.

Comment: The problem is that the read was valid when performed, but the data retrieved become stale after being read (superseded by the intervening update), so there isn't anything to 'protect against' (i.e. it already happened) other than the second update unwittingly overwriting the first update. The isolation levels have more effect when you talk about scenarios like (as one example): `T1 reads A, T1 updates A, T2 reads A (before T1 commits)`